Excel Ribbon Button toggleButton: Shrink to fit (text) - exclude charts from selection
This is a follow-up question to this one:
Excel Ribbon Button toggleButton: Shrink to fit (text)
The button works perfectly as long as you don't have any charts on your sheets.
If you have charts and the current selection happens to be a chart, the code stops working. Error: "Run-time error 91: Object or With block variable not set." For example, if a chart on Sheet1 is selected and you then click on Sheet2, the error message shows up.
How do you make the button work with charts in your workbook? How do you say: if the selection is a chart, "ignore and resume"?
Something like:
If Selection Is "ChartObject" Then Exit Sub Else
' -- XML

<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="LoadRibbon">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="Tabv3.1" label="TOOLS" insertAfterMso="TabHome">                  
        <group id="Group6" label="Alignment">
          <toggleButton id="ToggleButton1" 
                        label="Shrink to fit" 
                        imageMso="AsianLayoutCharacterScaling" 
                        size="large"
                        getPressed="ToggleButton1_Startup" 
                        onAction="ToggleButton1_OnAction"/>       
        </group>           
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>


' -- Standard Module

Option Explicit
Public RibUI As IRibbonUI

Sub LoadRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set RibUI = Ribbon
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton1"
End Sub

' ToggleButton 1 Startup
Sub ToggleButton1_Startup( _
   ByRef control As IRibbonControl, _
   ByRef returnedVal)
   returnedVal = (Selection.ShrinkToFit = True)
End Sub

' ToggleButton 1 Click
Sub ToggleButton1_OnAction( _
   ByRef control As IRibbonControl, _
   ByRef pressed As Boolean)
   Select Case pressed
      Case True
            Selection.ShrinkToFit = True
      Case False
            Selection.ShrinkToFit = False
   End Select
End Sub


' -- ThisWorkbook

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton1"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton1"
End Sub


Do you want shrinking something else then Ranges? If not, you can use If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" then Selection.ShrinkToFit = True/False. If you want to exclude only charts you can use If not TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" then Selection.ShrinkToFit = True/False...

Shrink to fit should only apply to text in cells.

Or in case of excluding only a chart If TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" then Exit Sub, in the context of your code... To work only with ranges If not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" then Exit Sub.

This means it should work only for ranges. A cell is a Range...

Like this? Sub ToggleButton1_Startup(...) If not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" then Exit Sub returnedVal = (Selection.ShrinkToFit = True) End Sub

returnedVal = (Selection.ShrinkToFit = True) must be on the next line. The code will  not reach it if selection is not of the "Range" type... It rases the error only if it runs/evaluates the respective code line. But why don't you try it? It won't bite, even if it will not do what you need... :-)

Yes, I did. It seems to work! I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything :-) So just for clarification: that line is all it needs for both "Startup" and "Click"? No further modifications needed?

Yes. You need to stop both procedures if Selection is not a Range.

Does this answer your question? Excel Ribbon Button toggleButton: Shrink to fit (text) - disable if selection is not range
